# Change both state and params dynamically in ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router I would like to set the ui-sref directive dynamically inside an ng-repeat, like so:

```
<a ng-repeat="step in steps" ui-sref="{{step.state(step.param)}}"></a>
```

Where *steps* is an array of "state objects" each with its own state and param object:

```
var steps = [{state: 'foo', param: {id: 'bar'}}, {...}];
```

That throws an interpolation error. On the other hand, passing only the state OR param dynamically works great per below:

```
// Pass only dynamic state works great
<a ng-repeat="step in steps" ui-sref="{{step.state}}"></a>
// Pass only dynamic param works great
<a ng-repeat="step in steps" ui-sref="foo(step.param)"></a>
```

I tried using ng-click as a hacky workaround but it didn't play well with the ui-sref-active:

```
<a ng-repeat="step in steps" ng-click="$state.go(step.state, step.param)"></a>
```

Is anyone familiar with a good way to pass both state and param dynamically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think ui-sref will parse what is inside the `(` and `)` as an expression.

So all you have to do is this.

```
<a ng-repeat="step in steps" ui-sref="{{step.state}}(step.param)"></a>
```

Not sure if the above would work, but that's the first thing I would try.

Comment: Keep in mind that ui-router will also create `href` attribute from your dynamic variable but it won't update it on change and link will always point to initial variable value

Comment: Work out pretty awesome