# Angular ui.router dynamic ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app with 2 states:

- `profile`
- `settings`

I have a link that repeats in my whole app:

```
<a ui-sref="profile({id:profile.id})" ui-sref-active="active">Current state + ID</a>
```

How can I change the `ui-sref` to be dynamic? - to represent the current state along with the current stateParam that I want (which is `id`)

when finding a solution, keep in mind that I want to be abble to use `ui-sref-active` so I'd rather avoid ng-click on something like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear what you mean with dynamic and the stateParam variables...

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters)

Comment: Use $state.href() and ng-href as explained here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349731/dynamically-set-the-value-of-ui-sref-angularjs)

Answer (score 6):

I think `ui-sref` will parse what is inside the ( and ) as an expression.

So all you have to do is this.

```
<a ng-repeat="step in steps" ui-sref="{{step.state}}(step.param)"></a>
```

Comment: can you post a snippet with this? Look good but not sure if will work...thou

Comment: [Change both state and params dynamically in ui-sref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997064/change-both-state-and-params-dynamically-in-ui-sref)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most safe and understandable way is using simple `if else`:

```
<div ng-if="checkState == 'profile'">
      <a ui-sref="profile({id:profile.id})" ui-sref-active="active">Current state + ID</a>
</div>

<div ng-if="checkState == 'settings'">
      <a ui-sref="settings({id:profile.id})" ui-sref-active="active">Current state + ID</a>
</div>
```

sure that will work...

Comment: It will, but I can't do that. Here, I have 2 states but in my actuall app I have more than 2. I can't create mountains of conditions. It's a good solution, but not for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.routers = [
  {
    state: 'profile',
    params: {id: 1}
  },
  {
    state: 'settings',
    params: {id: 1}
  } 
];
```

View:

```
<a ng-repeat="router in routers" ui-sref="{{router.state}}(router.params)"></a>
```

Comment: {{router.state}}() -- () brackets also needed.